# Are order-preserving field embeddings unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ring-homomorphism, ordered-fields

Let $K$ be an ordered field with an embedding into $\mathbb R$,

$$f:K\hookrightarrow\mathbb R,$$

where $f$ is order preserving. Is $f$ unique?

---

Follow up from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626745/are-field-embeddings-unique/3626758?noredirect=1#comment7454379_3626758) question of mine (same question but without ordering assumption). [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297954/embedding-ordered-number-fields-into-bbb-r) question is related, but not quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in that case it is unique, because for any $x\in K$, its image $f(x)$ is completely characterized by the sets $A=\{a\in \mathbb{Q}|a\leqslant f(x)\}$ and $B=\{b\in \mathbb{Q}|f(x)\leqslant b\}$, and we see that $A=\{a\in \mathbb{Q}|a\leqslant x\}$ and 
$B=\{b\in \mathbb{Q}|x\leqslant b\}$ so they only depend on the order on $K$.

Comment: You don't need $B$. The second $A$ is actually $f^{-1}(A)$.

Comment: @lhf Sure, but $f^{-1}(A)=A$ since field morphisms act trivially on $\mathbb{Q}$. (I agree about $B$ being useless, I think I put it for symmetry.)